# What trouble will I run into if I modify a date-stamp file in a Git pre-commit hook and simply call "git add timeStamp.cs"?

Tags: git, pre-commit-hook

There are several threads on this forum that in some way touches this subject, but being a beginner at Git I don't understand them and I can't get them to work properly. I have a C#-project that I would like to link-in the commit date and time into using a Git pre-commit hook. When I try the following, it seems to work fine:

```
cmd.exe /c "getTimeStampAndUpdateTimeStampFile.exe"
git add timeStamp.cs
```

However, most code snippets I have found while searching the Internet are A LOT more complex and usually involves stashing, but I don't understand why it's needed. Could someone please explain, *in simple terms*, what the disadvantages of my simple approach is and when will this cause me problems?

Comment: The real question here is _why_ you're doing this - git commits already come with baked-in timestamp data. Perhaps some background on what you're trying to achieve with this would help?

Comment: In my C#-application there is a little "About"-dialog. In that dialog I would like to display, for example, the following text: "My Application, Committed on Thursday Nov 13, 2019 at 1:12:05 pm CET". I want the date and time to be updated automatically each time I commit.

Comment: Perhaps a better approach would be to add the timestamp as part of the build process, reading from the most recent commit?

Comment: It may seem strange, but I would like to avoid having my Visual Studio-project being dependent on Git. You see, every once in a while I have to distribute my C#-application to colleagues, that don't have access to the software network drives, and customize the application a little for them. What I do in those cases is zip the project and email it to them and then install Visual Studio Express 2005 and sit down together with them and do the customizations. So in those cases the commit date and time will be unknown with your approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Sebastian Lenartowicz suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58841795/what-trouble-will-i-run-into-if-i-modify-a-date-stamp-file-in-a-git-pre-commit-h#comment103958123_58841795), other alternatives are probably a better idea, but to answer the question:

> What trouble [could] I run into

we need to understand that Git does not build commits from what is in your *work-tree* (the place where you can see and work with files), but rather from the *index*.

The TL;DR here is that some `git commit` options result in secret additional index files being used, such that your `git add` may affect *one* commit, but not *subsequent* commits.

#### Long

The index, which is also called the *staging area* or (rarely these days) the *cache*, is mostly<sup>1</sup> just a data structure inside a file in the `.git` directory called `index`.  That is, `git commit` generally opens and reads `.git/index` to see what to put in the new commit.<sup>2</sup>

The thing is, you can—and Git can internally—redirect itself from *the* index to some *alternative* index.  You do this, or Git does it itself, by setting the environment variable `GIT_INDEX_FILE` to hold some file name.  This affects each `git subcommand` command, including `git add`, so that `git add` will copy files into the alternative index instead of into the main index.

When you run a regular, ordinary `git commit`, Git:

- uses the regular index (so `GIT_INDEX_FILE` is either unset, or set to name `.git/index`);
- runs your pre-commit hook, exiting early if it rejects the commit;
- locks the index against changes (no `git add`s while we're reading it!);
- builds the actual commit using whatever is in the index, writing the new commit hash ID to or through `HEAD`; and
- unlocks the index.

But you can also run `git commit --only` or the default `git commit --include` *with file names*, and/or use `git commit -a`.  These have the effect of making the new commit from an index that has files "pre-added" to it.  To make this work, Git builds an *alternative, temporary* index.  That is, *the* index—the main index for this work-tree, whichever file it lives in—is not modified yet.  It still matches whatever was in it before you started this particular `git commit` command.  The alternative index is filled in from:

- the `HEAD` commit if you used `git commit --only`: we want a commit that is like `HEAD` but has some updates, or
- the current index if you used `git commit --include`: we want a commit that's equivalent to `git add`ing some files, but if the new commit *fails* for some reason, we don't want the files added to *the* (main) index.

If you used `git commit -a`, Git now runs the internal equivalent of `git add -u` to update this temporary index in same the way `git add -u` updates any index.  If you specified particular files, Git now runs the equivalent of `git add` on each of those files.  Either way, this temporary index is now updated to hold the proposed new commit.

So now, we have an alternative temporary index that holds what should go into the new commit.  If this new commit is successful, Git will need to update the *real* index as well, so Git may need to build an updated real index, too.

At this point there are either two or three index files:

1. The main / real index.
2. Our temporary index.
3. The projected new main index.

If our temporary one *is* the projected new one—i.e., we used `git commit --include` rather than `git commit --only`—the temporary and projected-main are the same file: files 2 and 3 are both just named `.git/index.lock` (or a different path for an added work-tree).

Git now runs your pre-commit hook as usual, but `GIT_INDEX_FILE` is set to point to file #2—the temporary index being used for the duration of this `git commit`.  If your hook uses `git add`, it will add these files to file #2.

If the commit *fails*, Git just rolls everything back: the (main) index remains unchanged.  The `git add` you ran in your hook is effectively undone.

If the commit *succeeds*, though, Git now renames index file #3—the prepared, updated index—to be the main index.  The `git add` you did to file #2 *vanishes* unless files 2 and 3 are the same file.  This is not necessarily terribly harmful—the user can just run `git add` again—but it's definitely weird.

---

<sup>1</sup>There are multiple reasons for the word *mostly* here, but the general idea is: there's some file, and for various purposes, you can—or Git can—use a *different* file, sometimes.

<sup>2</sup>If you're in an added work-tree, the (main / default) index is in a different location under the `.git` directory.  Each work-tree has its own private default index.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the very elaborate and informational post.